# Connected sum of two cylinders

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

What is the connected sum of 2 cylinders (polygon with identifies edges) if we are doing via atlas
Whenever I am adding, I am left with 3 holes instead of 4 and I don't know how to explain here without figure

Answer (score 0):

-->--       -->--
|           | + |            |
 -->--       -->--
If these are 2 cylinders with 2 holes each, after taking connected sum the resultant gives 3 holes only